# How to check if a subfolder exists and if so add it to the path automatically on cd?

Tags: bash, path, cd-command

On my Ubuntu machine, I have a lot of javascript / typescript projects.

Each of npm's binary might have a global installation, like `tsc` at

```
~/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/bin/tsc
$ tsc -v
Version 2.4.2
```

and it each project will define its own binary at:

```
~/src/project/node_modules/.bin/tsc 
$ cd ~/src/project && ./node_modules/.bin/tsc -v
Version 2.3.4
```

I have a lot of nodejs / typescript projects, and whenever I call a command, e.g. `tsc`, I always want to run the project's as the first choice, and only then fallback to the global installation.

I know that npm scripts will always call the command from `./node_modules/.bin/` and hence setting up scripts like:

```
$ jq .scripts package.json 
{
  "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-register --recursive tests/unit",
  "start": "node start.js",
  "start-dev": "nodemon start.js",
  "tslint": "tslint 'src/**/*.ts?(x)' --fix",
  "tsc": "tsc"
}
```

would suffice. I could then call:

```
> pink_elephant@1.0.0 tsc /home/philipp/myProject
> tsc "-v"

Version 2.3.4
```

Yet not all my projects have these scripts defined, and I find handling the arguments via `--` annoying.

So in order of making my life as a developer easier, I like to define my path in a way, that whenever I:

```
cd someProjectFolder
```

it looks for the existence of:

```
./node_modules/.bin/
```

and if it exists, add it to the path of the current shell.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: are you really sure you want to do this?  you'll end up with an enormous PATH and you'll never be sure which program of any given name you're about to run.   I think this is a bad idea, so I'm not going to write an answer, only a pointer in the right direction: writing a function wrapper around `cd` would probably be your best bet here.  You don't want this to happen every time you display the shell prompt, only when you enter a directory.   hmmm....implementing this as a (i.e. a pushpath/poppath analog to `pushd`/`popd`) might be interesting and useful way to do this)

Comment: @cas Yes, as currently I often run into the problem of running the global installation by mistake and I get tired of typing `./node_modules/.bin/`. I understand the danger that some script kiddie might hijack the `rm` command in a npm package, yet that's what I have backups for. It's maybe something to keep in mind when writing the script, that it also lists the commands that are now registered.

Comment: damn and now i notice i deleted a word.  the missing word before the `(i.e.` is *stack* in case it's not obvious.   re: listing paths, that's part of the reason i suggested a stack like `pushd`.   the `dirs` command in bash allows you to view and manipulate the directory stack.   so, write a `pushpath` function, a `poppath` function, a `paths` function, another function to parse your `.scripts` file and then a wrapper function around `cd` to change the PATH if/as required.

Comment: btw, these need to be functions (or maybe aliases if they're simple enough).  They can't be external scripts/programs because they have to manipulate the environment of your shell (`$PATH` variable.  and whatever array var you use for the stack) - and a child can't change parent's env.

Comment: If you're always in the top level of your project when you call stuff, you could simply add `./node_modules/.bin/` to your path. You could even cheat and add `../node_modules/.bin/` as well, but I don't know how many levels of directories you have in your projects.

Comment: For my special use case, one can use yarn instead. yarn is a npm replacement, and it looks automatically in the node module bin folder, hence `yarn tsc` will execute the proper binary.